# How to bake normal map with alpha in Cycles

Tags: transparency, baking, normal-map

Is there in Cycles any way to bake normal map from highpoly to low poly mesh with *alpha* like below on the picture? It works with other "Bake Types" like "Combined" etc. but when I try to bake normal map alpha is not part of the baked map. I would bet that it worked in earlier Blender versions.

[image]

Comment: I would say that for these types of normal maps you don't really need alpha maps. Since the outside area is "neutral" it wouldn't affect surrounding normals when projected in Substance Painter or other program. However, if there is in fact a possibility to bake alpha maps in one step, I would like to know it!